# When was the third heaven where God dwells created

Tags: heaven

When was the third heaven where God dwells created?  Was it created during the creation week?

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This question is off-topic and does not fit into one of the [question types that the community finds acceptable.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-or-template-questions-that-the-community-generally-finds-ac) If possible, edit this question so that it better fits into one of those question types.

Comment: I think you would have better luck starting by asking what is meant by the "third heaven" in scripture. The answer to that question will probably render this one obsolete.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This next has nothing to do with the quality of your question, it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

Answer (score 5):

Just so we all know what you're talking about...

> **2 Corinthians 12:2 ESV** I know a man in Christ who fourteen years ago was caught up to the **third heaven**—whether in the body or out of the body I do not know, God knows.

Whether Paul was talking about a literal third heaven or a metaphorical vision, I am not sure. But **if** there is one, my guess is that it would be included with the *heavens* talked about in Genesis 1:1.

> **Genesis 1:1 ESV** In the beginning, God created the *heavens* and the earth.

Though I wouldn't say that God dwells there as he *created* it

> **Isaiah 66:1,2 ESV** Thus says the Lord: “**Heaven is my throne**, and the earth is my footstool; what is the house that you would build for me, and what is the place of my rest?
>   **All these things my hand has made**, and so all these things came to be, declares the Lord. But this is the one to whom I will look: he who is humble and contrite in spirit and trembles at my word.